using chapter style in latex (book)
I want to replicate the following chapter style using LaTeX

I wrote a code, but I was only able to make it work for the beginning of the document and not as a style
\newlength{\mywordlength}
    \settowidth{\mywordlength}{\textsc{\textbf{capítulo}}} % Calculate the width of "word"

\newlength{\mywordheight} % Define a new length
\settoheight{\mywordheight}{\textsc{\textbf{Capítulo}}} % Calculate the height of the word "word"



\begin{tikzpicture}
    % This is for the red square
    \draw [draw=red, fill=red!70](0,0) rectangle (\the\mywordlength,\the\mywordheight*6);
    % This is to center the letter vertically and horizontally
    \node [color=white] (t1) at  (\the\mywordlength/2,\the\mywordheight*3) {\Huge{\textbf{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\Roman{chapter}}}}};
    % This is for the empty square
    \draw [draw=white, fill=white ](0,\the\mywordheight*6) rectangle (\the\mywordlength,\the\mywordheight*7.8);
    % This is for the chapters
    \node [color=black] (t2) at  (\the\mywordlength/2,\the\mywordheight*6.9){\textsc{Chapter}};
    % This is for the line
    \draw [line width=1.25pt](\the\mywordlength+\the\mywordheight*2,\the\mywordheight*4.5) --(\the\mywordlength*7+\the\mywordheight,\the\mywordheight*4.5);
    % This is for the titles
    \node [color=black] (t3) at  (\the\mywordlength*4+\the\mywordheight*3/2,\the\mywordheight*2.25){\textbf{\huge{Here is the title.}}};
\end{tikzpicture}


Welcome in TeX.SX// The key idea would be to \renewcommand{\@make chapterhead}{...}with ... including your tikz code.

Using Roman numerals for chapter numbers may cause large boxes (like XXXIII). What are your plans/ideas for such cases?

I have removed two irrelevant tags (tcolorbox & titlesec) as you don't use nor need the related packages, if you choose the tikz way. On another hand, the requested formating is simple enough to be  achieved without tikz with builtin LaTeX features and  colortbl package.

The package titlesec will help you to customize the chapter and section headings.
You can try this:
\documentclass{book}
%
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newlength{\mywordlength}
    \settowidth{\mywordlength}{\textbf{capítulo}} % Calculate the width of "word"

\newlength{\mywordheight} % Define a new length
\settoheight{\mywordheight}{\textbf{Capítulo}} % Calculate the height of the word "word"

% Define the chapter title format
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\raggedright}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=red, minimum width=\mywordlength, minimum height=\mywordheight*6] 
      at (\the\mywordlength/2,\the\mywordheight*3) 
      {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily{\color{white}\Roman{chapter}}};
    \node [color=black] at  
      (\the\mywordlength/2,\the\mywordheight*6.9)
        {\scshape\chaptertitlename};
    \draw [line width=1.25pt] 
      (\the\mywordlength+\the\mywordheight*2,\the\mywordheight*4.5) --(\the\mywordlength*7+\the\mywordheight,\the\mywordheight*4.5);
    \node [color=black] at 
    (\the\mywordlength*4+\the\mywordheight*3/2,\the\mywordheight*2.25)
      {\huge\bfseries#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some title}

\setcounter{chapter}{20}
\chapter{Some other title}

\end{document}



